# Как можно восстановить соединение в ADO при разрыве связи?

Tags: ado, delphi, sql

Как можно восстановить соединение в ADO при разрыве связи?
Иногда идут обрывы связи из сетевой карты поэтому вылазят куча ошибок и недовольства у пользователей. Как можно на автомате его восстанавливать ?

Comment: может поможет значение таймаута увеличить в настройках

Comment: Что такое ADO ? О какой сети Вы говорите - IP ?

Answer (score 1):

Обрабатывайте при открытий или выполнения запроса, при подключений ADO к серверу try except -ом.
По моему , лучше написать свою функцию ,или же написать свой класс наследуя АДО.

Comment: так будет не глупо нет?
наверно как то можно условие сделать для ADOConnection при дисконекте по таймеру пытаться восстановить связь. только я не знаю как это написать.

Comment: <pre>на onEnebled таймера нужно сделать попытку:
begin
timer.enabled:=false;
try
adoconnection.connect;
except
timer.interval:=2000;
timer.enabled:=true;exit;
end;

end;
Потом в коде что то в духе:
try
adoconnection.connect
except
tryconnect.enabled:=true;
end;</pre>

Answer (score 1):

Никакие таймеры не нужны. Самый лучший способ восстановить соединение с базой - **снова начать использовать его** чтобы отловить разрыв соединения в блоке `try..except end;`

Вот примерный код:

```
// Процедура восстанавливает соединение и подключает датасет
procedure RespawnConnection;
begin
  FConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  FADODataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  with FConnection do
  begin
    ConnectionString := AdoConnectionString; // здесь настройки соединения
    LoginPrompt := False;
    Connected := True;
  end;
  FADODataSet.Connection := FConnection;
end;

// публичная функция для запросов к базе
function Query(const sql: string): TADODataSet;
begin
  try
    Result := FADODataSet;
    FADODataSet.CommandText := sql; // если not Assigned(ADODataSet),
                                    // тогда здесь будет исключение...
    FADODataSet.Open;
  except
    RespawnConnection; // ...которое будет обработано...
    Result := Query(sql); // ...с повторением этого же запроса
  end;
end;
```

Старайтесь не использовать таймеров для поллинга доступности ресурсов. В большинстве случаев это весьма плохая практика написания кода. К тому же, даже несмотря на мощь современных процессоров и доступность памяти, посоветую вам бережно относиться к использованию опеативной памяти и ресурсов машины.

Comment: Имейте в виду утечку памяти, при постоянном создании новых `TADOConnection` и `TADODataSet`, без освобождения старых (и без указания `Owner`-а).